# What is the definition domain of the function $(z^2-4)^i$, that is defined by the analytic branch of $Log(z)$, which is $L_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the definition domain of the function $(z^2-4)^i$, that is defined by the analytic branch of $Log(z)$, which is $L_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Note: the way I understood it, $L_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$. means all the plane except the positive imaginary axis.

Another note: I didn't understand the relation between Log(z) and the function itself.

I'm pretty sure that I translated the question from Hebrew in the best way possible, I hope the question is clear, because even in Hebrew i'm not fully sure about it. Anyway, as I explained above, I concluded that $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta \le \frac{5 \pi}{2}$ (that means anything but the positive imaginary axis, and also, not sure about that), and I tried to expand the expression:

$e^{ln(z^2-4)^{i}}=e^{iln(z^2-4)}=e^{i(ln(|
z^2-4|) + i(arg(z^2-4)+2\pi k)}$

and I got stuck here, not sure if this is the direction, I hope someone can help me out of this. any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but in the first line of the question body you write $z^2-3$, elsewhere you write $z^2-4$. Presumably, "defined by the analytic branch …" means that $(z^2-4)^i$ is defined as $\exp \bigl(i\cdot L_{\frac{\pi}{2}} (z^2-4)\bigr)$. For which $z$ is that expression defined?

Comment: I corrected the 3.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think $z$ can be anything but points on the positive imaginary axis, because $exp$ is defined for every number, right  ?

Comment: Not quite. Indeed $\exp$ is defined everywhere, so we only need to look where $L_{\frac{\pi}{2}} (z^2-4)$ is defined. But when $z$ is purely imaginary, then $z^2 - 4$ is negative, so $L_{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is defined there.